# Postgresql, joining most recent row from one table to another based on dates

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-11

We have several tables we have to bring together to match the most recently effective price with the transaction date.  The simplified query is shown below:

```
SELECT t.transaction_id,
       price.*
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
            select p."Id" AS price_id, p."ProductPrice" AS price_product_price
            from "Prices" p
            INNER JOIN "PriceLists" pl ON pl."Id" = p."PriceListId"
            where p.product_id = t.product_id
            and pl.valid_from_date <= t.transaction_date
            ORDER BY pl.valid_from_date desc
            LIMIT 1) as price on true
WHERE t.source = {P1}
AND t.target = {P2}
```

The problem I am having is how to improve performance, we have transactions which have a date, we then have many thousands or price lists with each containing many thousands of prices.  The structure is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE public."PriceLists" (
    "Id" int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    "Name" text NULL,
    "ValidFromDate" date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_PriceLists" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

CREATE INDEX "IX_PriceLists_ValidFromDate_Desc" ON public."PriceLists" USING btree ("Id", "ValidFromDate" DESC);


CREATE TABLE public."Prices" (
    "Id" int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    "Price" numeric NOT NULL,
    "ProductId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "PriceListId" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Prices" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

When I run the query I am seeing this:

```
->  Index Only Scan using "IX_PriceLists_ValidFromDate_Desc" on public."PriceLists" pl  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=19908)
```

which has 19908 loops when the number of transactions returned in this query is only 316.

I moved the ValidFromDate to prices and added the same order by desc index on Prices and saw this:

```
->  Index Only Scan using "IX_Prices_ValidFromDate_Desc" on public."Prices" p  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=316)
```

We could move that column but it would mean updating all prices when we update the valid from date on a price list.  I'm trying to avoid denormalizing data if at all possible.  Do we have any options to improve performance in this scenario, happy to rewrite and move things around, whatever it takes to get the speed to the maximum possible for this type of join.

Execution Plans:

I can see problem, because the date is on the PriceList and not prices it does a large number of loops but if I put the ValidFromDate on prices and add an index with DESC it includes that in the index condition.

I guess my question is if there is a way to not move ValidFromDate to prices and get the same performance?

```
Nested Loop  (cost=12.78..31599.66 rows=2463 width=18) (actual time=0.464..481.879 rows=2463 loops=1)
  Output: t.transaction_id, t.product_id, p."Id", p."ProductPrice"
  Buffers: shared hit=800226
  ->  Seq Scan on public.transactions_temp t  (cost=0.00..67.53 rows=2463 width=39) (actual time=0.009..0.696 rows=2463 loops=1)
        Output: t.transaction_id, t.transaction_date, t.source, t.target, t.product_id
        Filter: ((t.source = 23) AND (t.target = 18))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 172
        Buffers: shared hit=28
  ->  Limit  (cost=12.78..12.78 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.195..0.195 rows=1 loops=2463)
        Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", pl."ValidFromDate"
        Buffers: shared hit=800198
        ->  Sort  (cost=12.78..12.78 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.194..0.194 rows=1 loops=2463)
              Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", pl."ValidFromDate"
              Sort Key: pl."ValidFromDate" DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=800198
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..12.77 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.012..0.176 rows=99 loops=2463)
                    Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", pl."ValidFromDate"
                    Inner Unique: true
                    Buffers: shared hit=800198
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_prices_valid_from_desc on public."Prices" p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.007..0.054 rows=107 loops=2463)
                          Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", p."PriceListId", p."ProductId", p.valid_from_date
                          Index Cond: ((p."ProductId" = t.product_id))
                          Buffers: shared hit=271885
                    ->  Index Only Scan using "IX_PriceLists_ValidFromDate_Desc" on public."PriceLists" pl  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=264156)
                          Output: pl."Id", pl."ValidFromDate"
                          Index Cond: ((pl."Id" = p."PriceListId") AND (pl."ValidFromDate" <= t.transaction_date))
                          Heap Fetches: 0
                          Buffers: shared hit=528313
Planning Time: 0.925 ms
Execution Time: 482.435 ms



Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..31521.98 rows=2463 width=18) (actual time=0.042..27.685 rows=2463 loops=1)
  Output: t.transaction_id, t.product_id, p."Id", p."ProductPrice"
  Buffers: shared hit=14817
  ->  Seq Scan on public.transactions_temp t  (cost=0.00..67.53 rows=2463 width=39) (actual time=0.009..0.696 rows=2463 loops=1)
        Output: t.transaction_id, t.transaction_date, t.source, t.target, t.product_id
        Filter: ((t.source = 23) AND (t.target = 18))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 172
        Buffers: shared hit=28
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..12.75 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=2463)
        Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", p.valid_from_date
        Buffers: shared hit=14789
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..12.75 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=2463)
              Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", p.valid_from_date
              Inner Unique: true
              Buffers: shared hit=14789
              ->  Index Scan using ix_prices_valid_from_desc on public."Prices" p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=2463)
                    Output: p."Id", p."ProductPrice", p."PriceListId", p."ProductId", p.valid_from_date
                    Index Cond: ((p."ProductId" = t.product_id) AND (p.valid_from_date <= t.transaction_date))
                    Buffers: shared hit=9862
              ->  Index Only Scan using "IX_PriceLists_ValidFromDate_Desc" on public."PriceLists" pl  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=2463)
                    Output: pl."Id", pl."ValidFromDate"
                    Index Cond: ((pl."Id" = p."PriceListId"))
                    Heap Fetches: 0
                    Buffers: shared hit=4927
Planning Time: 0.541 ms
Execution Time: 27.940 ms
```

Comment: I notice that you don't have a FOREIGN KEY link between the price and pricelist  tables - what happens if you add ALTER TABLE price ADD CONSTRAINT price_pricelist_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (price_list_id) REFERENCES price_list (id)? This should help. Also, I'd avoid (if I were you) the use of quoted identfiers - use snake_case instead for legibility - this is just a suggestion that I find helpful!

Comment: Also, please include the full output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (as text) and also the structure of the transaction table.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, agreed on the quotes, I've inherited this I'm afraid.  I've removed the transactions query from the equation and moved the data I wanted to transaction_temp.  I'm suspecting there isn't a good option here as the date value I need is on PriceLists but I need a covering index on Prices including the date to get the performance we need.

Comment: Why don't you put a trigger on the price_list table which updates a timestamp field on the price table with the current price - if I've understood your issue correctly?